# LibGDX batch.draw vs sprite.draw performance

Tags: performance, libgdx, textures, sprite, spritebatch

which performance is better between A and B?

A :
batch.draw(sprite, x, y, width, height);

B :
sprite.draw(batch);
sprite.setPosition(x,y);

rotation or resizing may be involved.
if you think about performance rather than convenience, what would be better?

Comment: Voting to reopen because the question is perfectly clear to users of libGDX.

Comment: The question closed too quickly...
I want to reopen.
Thank you so much for your kind answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These don't have equivalent results, so there's no point in comparing their performance. The first (A) completely ignores all characteristics of the Sprite like color, position, scale, and rotation. It should never be used and is only possible because of the unfortunate design decision to have Sprite be a subclass of TextureRegion. A design mistake that I think the original creators of libGDX admit based on comments made on GitHub.

The Sprite class in my opinion should not be used at all in most cases since it conflates a TextureRegion (image asset) with a game world object (simulation data). You should define your own GameObject class that has a TextureRegion variable and variables for the characteristics that you are using (width, height, scale, etc.). Then draw it using whichever `batch.draw` overload has parameters for all the characteristics you use.

To take it a step further, you can write your own Drawable abstract wrapper class that can has variants for holding either a TextureRegion or an `Animation<TextureRegion>`. Then you GameObject can reference a Drawable, and you can easily swap out different types of assets for a GameObject.

Comment: Is it a problem to use sprite? It's a sprite project already. That's a big deal.

Comment: Using Sprite leads to redundant code and hacky code when you want to animate or flip the texture region. But if you already did it that way, I don't think it's worth rewriting. Just be sure you understand exactly what the Sprite class is under the hood and how that differs from TextureRegion. The best way to do that is to read its source code.